# Gluten-free replacement for all-purpose flour in fried fish batter?

Tags: substitutions, frying, fish, gluten-free, batter

Recently, I've found a few good recipes for a **frying batter** for a **fish**. Unfortunately, all imply using all-purpose **wheat flour**.
exp. https://akispetretzikis.com/en/categories/pswmia-zymes/koyrkoyti

1. I'm looking for the closest possible (in terms of **taste** and **crunchiness**) **drop-in replacement** (mix of any, even relatively uncommon, **flours**, **starches**, and/or **thickeners** (exp.
   linseed, guar gum) as long as they are gluten-free) for the **wheat flour**.

I've tested mixtures from Schar and they were somewhat acceptable in terms of crunchiness but completely tasteless.

2. Every **gluten-free mixture** I've tested so far **burns too quickly** compared to the wheat counterpart. Do you have any method to mitigate this? Like a heat-resistance increasing ingredient for the mixture?

I was thinking about adding a bit of white corn flour (maiz blanco) as it is used primarily to make tortillas, but it makes the frying batter behave more like plasticine and gives it a noticeable taste, not suitable for a fish.

3. What do you think about using a **gluten-free mixture** designed for **pizza or bread** (exp. from **Caputo**)? I suppose it should be more heat resistant and crunchy, and similar in taste to the wheat counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if something is burning too quickly, you need to turn down the heat, and cook it for longer.

As for recommendations for gluten free batters, there are plenty of gluten free tempura batter recipes out there that use rice flour.  Although it's worth noting that tempura is usually only cooked to 'golden' in color, not fully 'brown'.

And if you're willing to go with a three part breading instead of a batter, you can use rice flour, egg, and (rice or corn) cereal crumbs.

Answer (score 0):

A tremendous gluten-free replacement for all-purpose flour in the fried fish batter would be a combination of almond and rice flour. Almond flour provides a nutty flavor, while rice flour gives the batter a light and crisp texture. To use these flours in a fish batter, mix 1 cup of almond flour and ½ cup of rice flour in a medium bowl. For a crunchier coating, you can add two tablespoons of cornstarch. Then, whisk together the ingredients until they are combined.